# jQuery Equal Height Columns

Tags: height, equals

http://shoes4school.project-x.me/get-involved.html

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong the the jQuery column faux... I can not get it to work after trying several different methods...

The code i'm using is... my url is above

$j(".content-block").height(Math.max($("#right").height(), $(".content-block").height()));

Comment: You shouldnt need jQuery to create two column layout. Proper CSS should do that without the JS, is there a reason why you just arent doing a traditional two column css layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to faux columns on webpage

```
(function($){
// add a new method to JQuery

$.fn.equalHeight = function() {
   // find the tallest height in the collection
   // that was passed in (.column)
    tallest = 0;
    this.each(function(){
        thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if( thisHeight > tallest)
            tallest = thisHeight;
    });

    // set each items height to use the tallest value found
    this.each(function(){
        $(this).height(tallest);
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work when smaller divs has margin or padding.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug show this error :

```
preloadImages is not defined
 preloadImages([
```

Comment: I fixed that error but the columns did not faux.  I wanted to you js because it's a quick and plus I'm modifying a joomla template...

Comment: Also this method has worked for me countless times... I'm not sure what the problem is..

Comment: (function($){
    // add a new method to JQuery
 
    $.fn.equalHeight = function() {
       // find the tallest height in the collection
       // that was passed in (.column)
        tallest = 0;
        this.each(function(){
            thisHeight = $(this).height();
            if( thisHeight > tallest)
                tallest = thisHeight;
        });
 
        // set each items height to use the tallest value found
        this.each(function(){
            $(this).height(tallest);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);